# "It is correct on both statements you sent to me" vs. "Both statements that you sent to me are correct"

Tags: difference, sentence-meaning

Please consider the conversation below:

> Me: "Is statement A correct?, also, is statement B correct?"
>   Answerer: "Yes, **it is correct on both statements you sent to me.**"

Does the sentence **"Yes, it is correct on both statements you sent to me."** in this context have equivalent meaning as the sentence

> "Both of the statements that you sent to me are correct"?

Thank you,

Comment: No. The first sentence does not imply that the entire statement is correct, while the second does.

Comment: @ColleenV hello, I just edited my original question - would the edit make any difference in answer?

Answer (score 2):

The two statements are not equivalent

> It is correct on both statements you sent to me.

the "it" refers to a specific point or part of the statements that were sent were correct, probably used when comparing the two statements for consistency in *something*

> Both statements that you sent to me are correct.

means the statements, in their entirety, are correct on their own, and may or may not have any connection to each other.

Comment: perhaps I wasn't clear on the context of the question sentence. I was given the sentence from the following conversation - Me: "Are the two statements correct?" Answerer: "Yes, it is correct on both statements you sent to me." - Does "Yes, it is correct on both statements you sent to me" have equivalent meaning to "Yes, both statements you sent to me are correct"? Thank you for your help,

Comment: I just edited my question as well, thank you for your help.